# Как добавить .gif на label PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt, qlabel, gif, qmovie

я хочу добавить **`gif.gif`** анимацию на `label`. Если ставить её как `pixmap`, то ничего не получается.

Как добавить **`gif.gif`** в обычный `label` без изменения его размера?

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 180, 171, 171))
        self.label.setText("")
        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("gif.gif"))
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        print('Gif label')


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> QMovie Class
>
> Этот класс используется для показа простой анимации без звука.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 180, 371, 371))    # 171, 171
        self.label.setText("")
        
#        self.label.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("gif.gif"))             # ---
        self.label.setScaledContents(True)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))

class ExampleApp(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        
        path='gif.gif'
        gif = QtGui.QMovie(path)                     # !!!
        self.label.setMovie(gif)
        gif.start()

        print('Gif label')


if __name__=="__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = ExampleApp()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]